# Update contact name during lead conversion process

Tags: leads, lead-conversion

I am creating custom lead conversion popup window similar to standard one in lightning experience. (There are some requirement because of that I need to create this custom popup).

I am trying to provide same functionality which standard popup has like
Create Account with different Name
Create contact with different name

etc.

For opportunity, I am able to find a method setOpportunityName in LeadConvert class. But I do not find any method for setting contact and account name upon lead conversion.

Is there any way to update the contact or account name during lead conversion process?

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though there's no method for doing so directly like you can for the Opportunity.  In this case, I would make use of [getContactId()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_dml_convertLead.htm#apex_Database_LeadConvert_getContactId) and [getAccountId()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_dml_convertLead.htm#apex_Database_LeadConvert_getAccountId), retrieve the Contact and Account based on the IDs returned, then update the applicable fields (`FirstName` and/or `LastName` on Contact, `Name` on Account) with DML as you normally would.

Comment: Thanks much for the quick response !! That's what I thought...